how to define 'allowed Capabilities' when using PSA (PodSecurity Admission) instead of PSP (Pod Security Policies) in k8s (kubernetes)
PSP (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-policy/) has been deprecated in k8s and to prevent pod escape we should only use PSA (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/security/pod-security-admission/) as of k8s v1.25.
I am able to add the following label to my Namespace and enforce the PSA restrictions.
pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce: restricted

However I need to allow certain capabilities for the POD creations. ( I have some side car containers that need NET_ADMIN and NET_RAW capabilities). In PSP that was possible by adding "allowedCapabilities:" as part of the PSP definition e.g.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/psp-to-pod-security-standards/#podsecuritypolicy-spec
 allowedCapabilities:
    - NET_ADMIN      # Allow NET_ADMIN capability

Is there a similar settings available in PSA or what is the least complex way to do the equivalent when using PSA instead of PSP?
